# Nested xml parsing in oracle table

Tags: xml-parsing

```
<company>
    <company_records>
        <company_name>aaaaa</company_name>
        <business_grp>abcd</business_grp>
        <employee>
            <field_id>52457</field_id>
        </employee>
        <address>
            <field_id>865567</field_id>
        </address>
        <agreement_start_date>01-FEB-2021</agreement_start_date>
        <agreement_end_date></agreement_end_date>
    </company_records>
    <company_records>
        <company_name>bbbb</company_name>
        <business_grp>hijk</business_grp>
        <employee>
            <field_id>79769</field_id>
        </employee>
        <address>
            <field_id>45824</field_id>
        </address>
        <agreement_start_date>09-FEB-2021</agreement_start_date>
        <agreement_end_date></agreement_end_date>
    </company_records>
</company>
```

Comment: You just forgot the question, and what you have done so far

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask